# Converting this MatLab iterating code to C#. Outputs from matlab and c# are different

Tags: c#, .net, matlab, code-conversion

I am trying to convert this code:

```
function [C] = cumulativeMaxV2(A)

cols = size(A,2);
bscans = size(A,3);

C = zeros(size(A));


for col = 1:cols
    for bscan = 1:bscans
        aline = A(:,col,bscan);
        for i = 1:length(aline)
            if i == 1
                C(i,col,bscan)=0;
            else
                C(i,col,bscan) = max(A(1:i-1, col,bscan));
            end
        end
    end
end
```

My C# code is below:

```
static double[,,] CumulativeMax(double[,,] A)
{
    int cols = 304; //A.GetLength(1);
    int bscans = 304; //A.GetLength(2);

    double[,,] C = new double[160, 304, 304];

    Console.Write("Processing... ");
    using (var progress = new ProgressBar())
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < cols; col++)
        {
            for (int bscan = 0; bscan < bscans; bscan++)
            {
                double[] aline = new double[160];
                for (int i = 0; i < 160; i++)
                    aline[i] = A[i,col,bscan];
                for (int i = 0; i < aline.GetLength(0); i++)
                {
                    if (i == 0)
                        C[i,col,bscan] = 0d;
                    else if (i == 1)
                    {
                        double[] temp = new double[i];
                        for (int x = 0; x < i; x++)
                            temp[x] = A[x,col,bscan];
                        C[i,col,bscan] = temp.Max();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        double[] temp = new double[i - 1];
                        for (int x = 0; x < i - 1; x++)
                            temp[x] = A[x,col,bscan];
                        C[i,col,bscan] = temp.Max();
                    }
                }
            }
            progress.Report((double)col/cols);
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Done."); 
    return C;
}
```

Outputs from MatLab do not match those from the C# code.

Any pointers to where the bugs are in my C# code would be great. I'm not very good with MatLab.

I think this may be due to how MatLab's `max` function deals with infinity and NaNs.

Comment: your loop/loop/loop to initialize to zero isnt necessary...its a simple data type and already a 0

Comment: get rid of the aline loop...you aren't using it...replace with for (int i = 0; i < C.GetLength(0); i++)

Comment: Are the arrays values the same?  the Matlab is looking at the numbers up to the diagonal of Matrix A 1:i-1 : C(i,col,bscan) = max(A(1:i-1, col,bscan));